# I'm trying to create my first module on npm, but npm gives error

Tags: npm, ecmascript-6, node-modules

I'm trying to create my first module on npm, did everything according to the webpack instructions, but as a result, the module does not want to be assembled, and all npm fail. Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong?

https://1drv.ms/u/s!AlMuIOVIeFkLkZI5yilbtxjXk5OjWw

module name - awescode-testcafe

Comment: The npm package `awescode-testcafe` has no README and has source code embedded. The package you have created is named `testnpm`. This name already exists on npm so you cannot publish your package without changing its name. But I would be interested to know what you want to achieve with such a package.

Comment: No, the package I'm doing is awescode-testcafe, and when I import testcafe into it, it gives an error. testnpm is only a demo wrapper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to achieve is to execute following code:

```
export async function typeText(t, el, val) {
    await t
        .selectText(el)
        .pressKey('delete')
        .typeText(el, val)
        .expect(el.value).eql(val);
}
```

by calling the method `typeText(t, el, val)` within a browser after this code has been compiled by WebPack.

TestCafe actions have not been designed to execute in the browser, they must run in a NodeJs application.
Therefore in your module `awescode-testcafe` you should develop a NodeJs App instead of a Web App.